How to tell waf to wait for recurse to finish before continuing?
I'm using waf's bld.recurse to call a wscript in a subfolder. I need that operation to complete before the calling wscript continues on. How do I tell waf to wait for all the calls to bld() in the sub-wscript to finish before starting the bld calls in the calling wscript?

Found the solution here https://waf.io/book/#_build_groups. I just needed to call bld.add_group() after bld.recurse().
